# Adding time stamps to new columns

Tags: python, pandas

i have  a time column name 'timeStmap' contains date and time and i would like to struct the day the month the hour and add them to new columns in my data frame

this is my code

```
    year,hour,month,date,Week_day=zip(*[(d.year(),d.hour(),d.month(),d.day()) for d in df.timeStmap])
```

it shows the error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'timeStmap'

Comment: Could you please add some informating regarding how your dataframe looks like and the data you are working with ?

Comment: I suggest you look through [time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html). If you convert the column to the `datetime` dtype then you have all of this information readily available through the datetime accessors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something along these lines
just replicate for all the things you want

```
df['year'] = df.apply (lambda row: pd.Timestamp(row['timeStamp']).year, axis=1)
```

To do multiple columns..

```
def f(r):
    return pd.Timestamp(r).year, pd.Timestamp(r).month,pd.Timestamp(r).day
df['year'],df['month'],df['day'] = zip(*df['timeStamp'].map(f))
```

the function f(r) returns data in such a way for the following timestamp - "2019-12-23"

```
returns - 2019,12,23
```

you map this function to every row in the dataframe using map. 
You now you have a bunch of `2019,12,23  2019,12,24 2019,12,25 2019,12,26`

zip converts all of this into a list.. and is passed to the columns in the dataframe.

Comment: this will be good for each column name to new function but i would like to assign all the new data to new columns

Comment: @AnasOmar I think this does what you're asking for